# Laravel Way Generator still not working with Sublime Text 2

Tags: php, laravel-4, sublimetext2

Still can't get Jeffrey Way's Laravel 4 Generator to work with Windows 7. I have reset the php path for both generator and artisan to the following:

```
"php_path": "C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.3.8\\php.exe"
```

but when I try to generate a resource I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\generate.py", line 59, in call_artisan
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 842, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

I did reinstall the packages, I did restart ST2 as administrator. None of these helps.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Tried generating the resource from windows command line directly?

Comment: I had not tried that because I assumed that it was no longer the correct approach. I have installed all other packages via package control. However, following your comment and having tried everything else, I uninstalled Generator and reinstalled using the terminal. To my delight it worked immediately. Many thanks for pushing me down that road - I'm a very happy guy!

Comment: Added an answer with some explanation so this question can be answered and closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 will call the command line version, so going directly to that route rules out the possibilities of programs causing the issues which it seems was the case.

Installing from the terminal / sublime text 2 shouldn't make a difference although I do not use ST2. You should be using the terminal for these sorts of things rather than ST2 as you will encounter less issues and the `artisan` commands are trivial.